# c++ functions return by value

Tags: c++, c++11

Confused by the following code, at least two constructors should have been called, one for variable tmp in funcReturningA and one for variable a in main. But the output is only a single line:

> constructor with args

```
#include <iostream>                                                             
using namespace std;                                                            

class A {                                                                          
    private:                                                                    
            int member;                                                            
    public:                                                                     
            A() {                                                                  
                    cout << "Default constructor" << endl;;                        
            }                                                                      
            A(int member) {                                                        
                    this->member = member;                                         
                    cout << "constructor with args" << endl;                       
            }                                                                      
            A(const A &a) {                                                        
                    cout << "copy constructor by ref" << endl;;                    
            }                                                                      
            A &operator=(const A &a) {                                             
                    cout << "copy assign operator by const ref" << endl;           
            }                                                                      
            A &operator=(A) {                                                      
                    cout << "copy assign operator by value" << endl;               
            }                                                                      
};                                                                                 

A funcReturningA() {                                                               
        A tmp(10);                                                                 
        return tmp;                                                                
}                                                                                  

int main(int argc, char **argv) {                                                  
........                                                                           
        A a = funcReturningA();                                                    
        return 0;                                                                  
}
```